# Franck-Condon factors in photoelectron spectroscopy

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, spectroscopy, theoretical-chemistry

Franck-Condon factors have been used to predict / assign the vibrational structure of photo-electron spectra.

$FCF=|\langle\psi''_{vib}|\psi'_{vib}\rangle|^2 = |\langle\psi''_{vib,1}\psi''_{vib,2},\ldots,\psi''_{vib,n}|\psi'_{vib,1}\psi'_{vib,2},\ldots,\psi'_{vib,n-1}, \psi'_{vib, emitted}\rangle|^2=|\langle\psi''_{vib,1}|\psi'_{vib,1}\rangle|^2\ldots|\langle\psi''_{vib,n}|\psi'_{vib,emitted}\rangle|^2$,

Question: what is $\psi'_{vib,emitted}$? Is it just a free particle, with its wavefunction spanning all space, hence it doesn't have any effect on the integral?

Comment: Yes it seems that you are correct that the final wavefunction  is a plane wave. This presentation gives some detail that you might find interesting ; http://photon-science.desy.de/sites/site_photonscience/content/e62/e189219/e189559/e190086/e190091/e190093/infoboxContent203186/xray-14_eng.pdf

Answer (score 1):

$\psi^\prime_{vib, emitted}$ is an energy normalized continuum wavefunction. The Franck–Condon factors involving bound ($\psi_v$) and continuum states ($\psi_E$) are actually Franck–Condon densities that are functions of the energy.

The Franck–Condon factors and densities are related by a closure relation
$$ \sum_{v^{\prime\prime}}|\langle \psi_{v^{\prime\prime}}|\psi_{v^{\prime}}\rangle|^2 + \int |\langle\psi_{E^{\prime\prime}}|\psi_{v^{\prime}}\rangle|^2 dE^{\prime\prime} = 1$$

References:

[1] J. Tellinghuisen, The Franck-Condon Principle in Bound-Free Transitions, in Photodissociation and Photoionization, edited by K.P. Lawley (John Wiley & Sons, Ltd, 1985).

[2] R.J. Le Roy, Comput. Phys. Commun. 52, 383 (1989).